# Can't update packages, segmentation fault

Tags: apt, updates

When trying to apt update from terminal I get error messages.
After sudo apt update:

```
Hit:1 http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease          
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease             
Segmentation fault (core dumped)                       
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
Aborted
```

But if I try again, the error message looks a bit different:

```
Hit:1 http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Segmentation faultsts... 7%
```

I already disabled third-party repositories, it did not help.

EDIT: Problem has mysteriously disappeared even though I did not do anything.

EDIT: It came back even worse, Ubuntu crashed completely and then I was unable to start it again. Someone told me the reason for it could have been an update that was interrupted. I ended up reinstalling everything, now it is working.

Comment: Needless to say, a normal and working Ubuntu installation doesn't do this. Did you do anything with your system in particular? Could you in your post include: Ubuntu version (`lsb_release -a`), APT version (`apt --version`) and Python version (`python3 --version`).

Comment: Did you ever change the default 
python version?